# Find all the values for a nested attribute based on the value of another attribute document in MongoDB shell

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a bunch of documents in a mongoDB collection structured like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "11111",
    "headerInfo": [
      {
        "headerAttribute": "string"
      }
    ],
    "attributeCollection": [
      {
        "name": "attributeOne",
        "value": "foo",
        "metadata": false,
        "otherAttribute": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "attributeTwo",
        "value": "foo2",
        "metadata": false,
        "otherAttribute": "string"
      }
    ],
    "status": "active"
  },
  {
    "_id": "11112",
    "headerInfo": [
      {
        "headerAttribute": "string"
      }
    ],
    "attributeCollection": [
      {
        "name": "attributeOne",
        "value": "bar",
        "metadata": false,
        "otherAttribute": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "attributeTwo",
        "value": "foo2",
        "metadata": true,
        "otherAttribute": "string"
      }
    ],
    "status": "active"
  }
]
```

I want to get a list of all of the **unique values** that are used in {"attributeCollection.name" : "attributeOne"} - so a new document that is something along the lines of
`["foo", "bar"]`

I have messed around with https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/distinct/#mongodb-dbcommand-dbcmd.distinct and it just returns collections of documents. I have a feeling some combination of $elemmatch, $arrayElemAt and/or aggregation and/or projection is necessary.

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KphiWKgDtVX) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking for a flat array of unique `attributeCollection.value` where the `attributeCollection.name` is equal to `attributeOne` then you can use `aggregate`:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "attributeCollection.name": "attributeOne"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      v: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$attributeCollection",
          as: "ac",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$ac.name",
              "attributeOne"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$v"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      values: {
        $addToSet: "$v.value"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Explanation**:

1. `$match` : find the documents where `"attributeCollection.name": "attributeOne"`
2. `$project`: only output the `$attributeCollection` array objects where `"attributeCollection.name": "attributeOne"` by leveraging `$filter`.
3. `$unwind`: the resulting array which will be called `v`.
4. `$group`: by their `$v.value` and while doing that push the `$v.value` to an array but use `$addToSet` to push so that only unique values are added to the array.

See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ufTKCWj2qtq) for a working example.

Comment: Thanks! That's a lot more work than I thought it would be, but your solution works perfectly, and I learned a lot more about IntelliShell!